# Using collations with JSONB

Tags: postgresql, collation, case-sensitive, jsonb

I have a postgres database and a case insensitive collation.
The collation was created by

`CREATE COLLATION IF NOT EXISTS case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false)`. (I also have another collation the removes accents, so ILIKE probably can't be used)

In my table I have a JSONB column (here called "forms"). This is a jsonb array containing multiple keys. I now want to find the rows that have values with a specific string- case insensitively.

For example, the query `SELECT * FROM etymologies WHERE forms @> '[{"form": "bears"}]' ;` returns 3 entries. I now want to get the same 3 entries when I search for `SELECT * FROM etymologies WHERE forms @> '[{"form": "Bears"}]'`.

What would be the best way to achieve this?
I tried
`SELECT * FROM etymologies WHERE forms @> '[{"form": "Bears"}]' collate case_insensitive ;`, but this returns no results.

(I also tried creating an index, but was super unsure about the syntax: `CREATE INDEX forms_form_case_insensitive_index ON etymologies USING GIN ((forms->'form' collate case_insensitive));` did something (it ran as slow as a usual index creation), but I am not sure what exactly.)

Comment: To my knowledge JSON is required to be case sensitive and thus  I would be very surprised if any of the JSON operators would honer such a collation.

Comment: I haven't tried but [SQL/JSON Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) may help

Comment: @SahapAsci Thanks, although I probably can't use them due to performance reasons.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I also suspect that this is the case. My current thinking is that I need to hack something together with generated columns.

Comment: @Pux any use of "case-insensitivity" is somehow slow.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether a (custom) collation can be applied on a jsonb operator or not. I am guessing that you should somehow cast the value to text with `->>` operator then apply collation & index.

However, you can test any jsonb value with regular expression which leads us to a solution to your original problem.

[The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) has `like_regex` function which allows case-insensitive match with the flag `i`
Here is an example which returns `true` which means you can use it in where condition

```
SELECT 
  jsonb '[{"form": "Bears"}]' @? '$[*].form ? (@ like_regex "^bears$" flag "i")';
```

- `@?` : Does JSON path return any item for the specified JSON value
- `$[*].form` : take each value's `form` attribute from array.
- `?` : filter
- `@` : the value to be filtered in our case its "Bears"
- `like_regex` : apply regex
- `"^bears$"` : our regex to be applied
- `flag "i"` : case-insensitive

Here are some references;

- [SQL/JSON Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS)
- [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: You can apparently drop the `?` and `@`: "*A path expression can be a Boolean predicate, although the SQL/JSON standard allows predicates only in filters. This is necessary for implementation of the `@@` operator*", using only `@@ '$[*].form like_regex "^bears$" flag "i"'`. While not documented, passing multiple values into a boolean predicate [implicitly checks whether **any** of them match](https://dbfiddle.uk/7O1QfG4b).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and works.  The execution takes about a minute for me, so I might keep looking for a faster alternative.